# Application Monitoring using sql and shell script

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, opensearch, sre

we are using shell scripts and sql queries to monitor our application.
we are planning to migrate to cloud and use prometheus and openserch for monitoring.

Is there a way to execute oracle sql quires(get the number of active users etc) and store that data in  prometheus/openserch or even display the counts directly in grafana/kibana.

Also i want to run linux commands (netstat/ grep ) and get the data from the running servers and use that data in  prometheus/openserch or even display the counts directly in grafana/kibana.

I can do this by using java program and send the data to openserch/prometheus but i know it's odd. need to find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/logstash/) to query your oracle db and ingest the query results into opensearch. Some relevant docs:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/migrate-an-on-premises-oracle-database-to-amazon-opensearch-service-using-logstash.html
- https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-keep-elasticsearch-synchronized-with-a-relational-database-using-logstash